# Riak search on CRDT data types - memory backend

Tags: riak, riak-search, riak-kv

I am using riak2.2.3, and trying to search in a map bucket type, but nothing is ever returned.

I've configured a bucket type "dist_cache" on the memory backend:

```
# riak-admin bucket-type status dist_cache
dist_cache is active

active: true
allow_mult: true
backend: <<"memory_mult">>
basic_quorum: false
big_vclock: 50
chash_keyfun: {riak_core_util,chash_std_keyfun}
claimant: 'riak@127.0.0.1'
datatype: map
dvv_enabled: true
dw: quorum
last_write_wins: false
linkfun: {modfun,riak_kv_wm_link_walker,mapreduce_linkfun}
n_val: 3
notfound_ok: true
old_vclock: 86400
postcommit: []
pr: 0
precommit: []
pw: 0
r: quorum
rw: quorum
search_index: <<"expirable_token">>
small_vclock: 50
w: quorum
young_vclock: 20
```

I've then enable search in /etc/riak/:

```
search = on
```

Then I have configured an index, with the default schema and associated it with the bucket type (see above).

I can successfully store and retrieve values, using keys, in that bucket. I have stored 3 values in registers: binary data, integer (timestamp) and a string:

```
[
  {{"attrs", :register}, <<131, 97, 111>>},
  {{"iat_i", :register}, "1540923453"},
  {{"test_s", :register}, "paul"}
]
```

(displayed after formatting from Elixir shell, using Elixir's Riak library.)

However, nothing is found when I try searching these values:

```
iex(74)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "iat_i:[0 TO *]")
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(75)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "iat_i:1540923453")
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(76)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_s:paul")     
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(77)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_s:*")   
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
```

In addition, /var/log/riak/solr.log doesn't show any error message for these requests.

Am I missing something?
I needed to remove a few options from the java startup options, but now it seems java is up and running, and solr.log does show error message when trying malformed request.

**EDIT:**

After trying @vempo's solutions:

I have suffixed the field with _register, however it still does not work. Here is how the field is:

```
iex(12)> APISexAuthBearerCacheRiak.get("ddd", opts)                 
[
  {{"attrs", :register}, <<131, 98, 0, 0, 1, 188>>},
  {{"iat_i", :register}, "1542217847"},
  {{"test_flag", :flag}, true},
  {{"test_register", :register}, "pierre"}
]
```

but the search request still returns no result:

```
iex(15)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_register:*")   
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(16)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_register:pierre")   
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(17)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_register:*")        
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(18)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_flag:true")    
{:ok, {:search_results, [], 0.0, 0}}
iex(19)> :riakc_pb_socket.search(pid, "expirable_token", "test_flag:*")
```

Still know output in /var/log/riak/solr.log, and index seems correctly setup:

```
iex(14)> :riakc_pb_socket.list_search_indexes(pid)                       
{:ok,
 [
   [index: "expirable_token", schema: "_yz_default", n_val: 3],
   [index: "famous", schema: "_yz_default", n_val: 3]
 ]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you misunderstood my answer. I showed you exactly what your search query should look like _given your particular example_. E.g. "attrs" will be indexed as "attrs_register". So if your query is "test_register:*", then the field must be named "test" and not "test_register".

Comment: Misunderstood indeed, thanks for the detailed explanation. Didn't work yesterday, but retried and it now works. Wow! Will ask soon another question on managing in-memory cache and expiration keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searching within maps the rules are different. According to [Searching with Data Types](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/searching-data-types/#data-type-schemas), there are four schemas for maps, one for each embedded type:

- *_flag
- *_counter
- *_register
- *_set

So that in your case you should be searching `attrs_register`, `iat_i_register`, and `test_s_register`.

As a side note, the suffixes `_s` and `_i` are probably redundant. They are used by the default schema to decide the type of a regular field, but are useless with embedded datatypes).

**UPDATE**

And to sum up the rules:

- a flag field named `test` will be indexed as `test_flag` (query `test_flag:*`)
- a register field named `test` will be indexed as `test_register` (query `test_register:*`)
- a counter field named `test` will be indexed as `test_counter` (query `test_counter:*`)
- a set field named `test` will be indexed as `test_set` (query `test_set:*`)

This is nicely shown in the table in [Searching with Data Types: Embedded Schemas](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/searching-data-types/#embedded-schemas).

See also the definition of dynamic fields for embedded datatypes in the [default schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/basho/yokozuna/develop/priv/default_schema.xml), section `<!-- Riak datatypes embedded fields -->`.